# How to use import statements in <script> tags in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, module, es6-modules

Does anyone know how to do this correctly in your index.html in Angular 5+?

```
<script>
  import { env } from './environment';
  ...do something with env here
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Browser support for import / export is still experimental.

Comment: All of Angular uses import/export, so it's clearly working in the browser, just the compiled JS is referencing the modules some other way. Is some other statement I can use to reference the same variable?

Comment: Disregarding Angular specifically, if you use modules and import/export, those modules are usually transpiled into a single bundle.js by webpack or babel or a similar implementation before being used in the browser. It is not clear to me in the least what you are trying to do here. Do you have an Angular app? What do you want to do with `env`? If you are trying to solve a problem, tell us about the problem, not about the solution you think will maybe work.

Comment: I'm trying to access an exported object from a module in Angular's index.html file. It doesn't have to be env, it can be any exported module object.

Comment: The short answer is you can't do that directly. If you tell me what your goal is, I can probably help you. Which exported object do you want to access, and why?

Comment: I want to access an environment variable that is set in our configuration for local dev vs prod in order to dynamically control the loading of a service worker. I'm not really interested in spending too much time on the problem. The question above has a straightforward answer. Either it can be done or it can't.

Comment: Do you want to only load the service worker in production?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal

Comment: Right, so afaik, this is done with `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })`

Comment: I tried that...it doesn't work because our config is a little different. It's probably something to do with our angular.json file, but documentation on that is sparse and I don't really want to spend too much time digging into it. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Well, good luck then. Also, this has been a textbook [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).